# Change Listbox's selected item Backcolor in C#.net

Tags: c#

i need to change the backcolor of the selected item in listbox. Can you give me some code example? i've tried adding DrawItem event but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the listbox's `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed`.

Then assign these events:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.Index;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    foreach (int selectedIndex in this.listBox1.SelectedIndices)
    {
        if (index == selectedIndex)
        {
            // Draw the new background colour
            e.DrawBackground();
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.Bounds);
        }
    }

    // Get the item details
    Font font = listBox1.Font;
    Color colour = listBox1.ForeColor;
    string text = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();

    // Print the text
    g.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), (float)e.Bounds.X, (float)e.Bounds.Y);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Great.. Sorry for the late comment. Same Problem but i'm using listview this time. i was able to use the code but i'm having a trouble with multiple columns. problem is only the first column changes. i need all columns change

Comment: I see you've asked the question elsewhere - so I'll have a look at answering later if no-one else does.

Comment: Actually, i was able to solved this. but my problem now is when i hover over my listview, subitems disappear or flicker. but when i clicked one row, it appears again.do you know why?

Comment: I suggest you ask in the new question.